# Android layout design issue?

Tags: android

I have a tabbar application with the tab at the top. My second tab is a list view. When i select an item in the list view , it should open other list view. But the new list view should not take up the whole screen but should be confined below the tab bar ? How to go about doing this?

Comment: How are you defining your tab host layout? What is in your setContentLayout for the main tab activity?

Comment: In the main.xml , the tab host contains three tabs with one for an imageview , one for listview and the last one for another listview

Answer (score 1):

I find the best way is to use a vertical linear layout as your container. Set the layout height of the tab bar to wrap content and the list layout height to fill parent with a layout weight of 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<!-- Some code here you want -->

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_weight="50">  
</ListView>
<!-- here choose different values layout_weight according  to your desire it work 100% -->
```